# ERROR_WRONG_LABEL when trying to print wireless using Android Brother Sdk for label printer

Tags: android, printing, brother-print-sdk

I have trying to print using labels from my android app which using **wifi** commands **Brother QL-720NW label printer**. Since I performed factory reset on the printer , I'm getting this error

> **Problem:** ERROR_WRONG_LABEL( means wrong roll  specified in the sdk guide) error is thrown on print command, since I performed factory
>   reset on the printer .

**CODE:**

```
void printTemplateSample() 
    {
        Printer myPrinter = new Printer();
        PrinterInfo myPrinterInfo = new PrinterInfo();

        try{
            // Retrieve printer informations
            myPrinterInfo = myPrinter.getPrinterInfo();

            // Set printer informations
            myPrinterInfo.printerModel = PrinterInfo.Model.QL_720NW;
            myPrinterInfo.port=PrinterInfo.Port.NET;
            myPrinterInfo.printMode=PrinterInfo.PrintMode.FIT_TO_PAGE;
//                  :
            myPrinterInfo.paperSize = PrinterInfo.PaperSize.A4;


            myPrinterInfo.ipAddress="192.168.1.13";
            myPrinterInfo.macAddress="00:80:92:BD:35:7D";


            myPrinter.setPrinterInfo(myPrinterInfo);

            // Start creating P-touch Template command print data
//          myPrinter.startPTTPrint(1, null);
           Boolean val= myPrinter.startPTTPrint(6, null);
            Log.i("print", "startPTTPrint "+val);

            // Replace text
            myPrinter.replaceText("abcde");
//          myPrinter.replaceText("12345");

            // Trasmit P-touch Template command print data
            PrinterStatus status=myPrinter.flushPTTPrint();//ERROR thrown here
            Log.i("print", "PrinterStatus  err"+status.errorCode);

        }catch(Exception e){    
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

- I'm using there sample code from [here](http://www.brother.com/product/dev/mobile/android/sampleprojects/index.htm)
- **Objective** - my ultimate objective is to replace text in template and print but currently I'm not able to print anything
- I'm using [this](http://www.brother.com/product/dev/mobile/android/index.htm) Brother SDK.
- I tried the Brother sample code for android , it also gives the same error
- **BUT brother i print app and Ptouch software are successfully printing without any error.**

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: check settings of your printer..may be you have altered the settings.. :D

Comment: I just want to see if you had problem with the WiFi printer connection goes into Turned Off mode and if you found a way to reconnect from code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a `LabelInfo` object, since you have a Label Printer. It's not clear at all in the documentation. You need to set the label info after the printer info.

```
PrinterInfo info = myPrinter.getPrinterInfo();
info.paperSize = PrinterInfo.PaperSize.CUSTOM;

LabelInfo mLabelInfo = new LabelInfo();
mLabelInfo.labelNameIndex = 5;
mLabelInfo.isAutoCut = true;
mLabelInfo.isEndCut = true;
mLabelInfo.isHalfCut = false;
mLabelInfo.isSpecialTape = false;

myPrinter.setPrinterInfo(info);
myPrinter.setLabelInfo(mLabelInfo);
```

The `ERROR_WRONG_LABEL` means that you have a wrong value in `paperSize` or `labelNameIndex`.
I have a P750W label printer with a 24'' paper. I found that value `5` is the good one for this size, but I don't know for your printer.

Comment: About the `labelNameIndex` value, I finally found where the value came from. It's the result of `LabelInfo.PT.valueOf("W24").ordinal()`

Comment: Hi Mathieu, 
I am using QL_710W and I have exactly the same code as you do but I am still getting the following error : ERROR_WRONG_LABEL

what value should we put for the 1st parameter of :

Boolean val = myPrinter.startPTTPrint(1, null);

Comment: 24 millimeter label around a half inch

Comment: I have used same way as you have described, but still getting same error, will you please help me?

Comment: I have tried same as you have suggested, still not printing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251424/error-wrong-label-while-print-via-wifi-using-androids-brother-sdk?noredirect=1#50251424

Comment: `myPrinterInfo.labelNameIndex = myPrinter.checkLabelInPrinter();` is not working. Please help me in that

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and figured out that you should specify the `labelNameIndex` field to the `PrinterInfo` object. 
I had the `QL-810W` printer. I tried many values and nothing worked until I set it to:

```
   printerInfo.labelNameIndex = LabelInfo.QL700.W62RB.ordinal // -> 17
```

I figured out the correct value by making a for loop with all integers from 0 to 100 and logging the result until the printing succeeded with this value. I know this is not the optimal solution but I can't find any documentation or reference for these codes.

Here is the code I used to specify the PrinterInfo object:

```
    val printerInfo = PrinterInfo()
    printerInfo.printerModel = PrinterInfo.Model.QL_810W
    printerInfo.port = PrinterInfo.Port.NET
    printerInfo.orientation = PrinterInfo.Orientation.PORTRAIT
    printerInfo.paperSize = PrinterInfo.PaperSize.CUSTOM
    printerInfo.align = PrinterInfo.Align.CENTER
    printerInfo.valign = PrinterInfo.VAlign.MIDDLE
    printerInfo.printMode = PrinterInfo.PrintMode.ORIGINAL
    printerInfo.numberOfCopies = 1
    printerInfo.labelNameIndex = LabelInfo.QL700.W62RB.ordinal // -> 17
    printerInfo.isAutoCut = true
    printerInfo.isCutAtEnd = false
    return printerInfo
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**
I solved by setting the `workPath` attribute:

```
printerInfo.workPath = context.cacheDir.Path
```

I noticed that the `setPrinterInfo` was returning false and when trying to print I received the `WRONG_LABEL` error code. Debugging the code I figured out that it's related to file writing permission that Brother SDK requires. The documentation is confusing and mentions about needing the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` *if workPath* isn't set. Even having this permission I could not make it work. I solved by setting the `workPath` attribute as shown above.