# Android printing with Brother SDK via WIFI (ERROR_WRONG_LABEL)

Tags: android, printing, brother-print-sdk

I am creating an Android app that will be printing to a Brother QL-720NW Label printer. I have created a sample project for this.

I have imported the necessary JAR file in the libs folder and set the printer settings as suggested in the sample project from Brother. However I keep getting an error that the label is not correct.

I have already seen following thread [ERROR_WRONG_LABEL when trying to print wireless using Android Brother Sdk for label printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808548/error-wrong-label-when-trying-to-print-wireless-using-android-brother-sdk-for-la) 
about similar problem.

According the Brother manual labelNameIndex should be set to 5 in my case.

Here's my manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

And here's the printing part of my small demo project:

```
public void Print(){

    Printer myPrinter = new Printer();
    PrinterInfo myPrinterInfo = new PrinterInfo();
    PrinterStatus myPrinterStatus = new PrinterStatus();

    try{
        // Retrieve printer informations
        myPrinterInfo = myPrinter.getPrinterInfo();

        // Set printer informations
        myPrinterInfo.printerModel = PrinterInfo.Model.QL_720NW;
        myPrinterInfo.port=PrinterInfo.Port.NET;
        myPrinterInfo.printMode=PrinterInfo.PrintMode.FIT_TO_PAGE;
        myPrinterInfo.paperSize = PrinterInfo.PaperSize.CUSTOM;

        myPrinterInfo.ipAddress="192.168.0.193";
        myPrinterInfo.macAddress="00:00:00:00:00"; //hidden for security reasons

        LabelInfo mLabelInfo = new LabelInfo();
        mLabelInfo.labelNameIndex = 5;
        mLabelInfo.isAutoCut = true;
        mLabelInfo.isEndCut = true;
        mLabelInfo.isHalfCut = false;
        mLabelInfo.isSpecialTape = false;
        myPrinter.setPrinterInfo(myPrinterInfo);
        myPrinter.setLabelInfo(mLabelInfo);

        // Create bitmap
        Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.printtest);

        try{
            tView.append("Start" + "\n" );

            myPrinter.startCommunication();
            PrinterStatus printerStatus = myPrinter.printImage(bmap);
            myPrinter.endCommunication();

            tView.append(printerStatus.errorCode.toString() + "\n");

        }catch(Exception e){
            tView.setText(e.toString());
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        tView.setText(e.toString());
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: how you solved this error? Also have you implemented Brother printer PJ763 in your application via Bluettoth

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I fixed with:

```
printerInfo.printerModel = PrinterInfo.Model.QL_720NW;
printerInfo.port = PrinterInfo.Port.NET;
printerInfo.ipAddress = "...";

printerInfo.paperSize = PrinterInfo.PaperSize.CUSTOM;
printerInfo.paperPosition = PrinterInfo.Align.CENTER;
printerInfo.orientation = PrinterInfo.Orientation.LANDSCAPE;

printerInfo.labelNameIndex = LabelInfo.QL700.W50.ordinal();
printerInfo.isAutoCut = true;
printerInfo.isCutAtEnd = true;
```

But the line that made the difference was:

```
printerInfo.labelNameIndex = LabelInfo.QL700.W50.ordinal();
```

Where "W50" is the paper type. You can find that paper type id in the **[manual.pdf](http://www.brother.com/product/dev/mobile/android/download/index.htm#forAndroid)**

**NOTE**: we must use the ordinal value and not de Enum value.

Comment: I have used same way as you have described, but still getting same error, will you please help me?

Comment: Hello Siddhpura, create a new SO question (so you can reach a maximum number of users) and I'll give it a look as soon as I can.

Comment: Ok sure let me do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251424/error-wrong-label-while-print-via-wifi-using-androids-brother-sdk

Comment: `myPrinterInfo.labelNameIndex = myPrinter.checkLabelInPrinter();` is not working. Please help me in that