# ERROR_WRONG_LABEL while print via WIFI using Android's BROTHER SDK

Tags: android, brother-print-sdk

I have Brother QL-710W label printer, I have tried to print via WIFI using Brother's SDK but every time I am getting ERROR_WRONG_LABEL error,

I have tried

[ERROR_WRONG_LABEL when trying to print wireless using Android Brother Sdk for label printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808548/error-wrong-label-when-trying-to-print-wireless-using-android-brother-sdk-for-la/50250129#50250129)

[Android printing with Brother SDK via WIFI (ERROR_WRONG_LABEL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872204/android-printing-with-brother-sdk-via-wifi-error-wrong-label/38655746?noredirect=1#comment87518418_38655746)

but no solutions are working,

My code is below

```
mPrinterInfo.printerModel = PrinterInfo.Model.QL_710W;
mPrinterInfo.port = PrinterInfo.Port.NET;
mPrinterInfo.ipAddress = "192.168.8.100";
//mPrinterInfo.labelNameIndex = 5;
mPrinterInfo.paperSize = PrinterInfo.PaperSize.CUSTOM;
mPrinterInfo.paperPosition = PrinterInfo.Align.CENTER;
mPrinterInfo.orientation = PrinterInfo.Orientation.LANDSCAPE;

mPrinterInfo.labelNameIndex = LabelInfo.QL700.valueOf("W50").ordinal();
mPrinterInfo.isAutoCut = true;


mPrinterInfo.isAutoCut = true;
mPrinterInfo.isCutAtEnd = true;

LabelInfo mLabelInfo = new LabelInfo();
mLabelInfo.labelNameIndex = LabelInfo.QL700.valueOf("W50").ordinal();
mLabelInfo.isAutoCut = true;
mLabelInfo.isEndCut = true;
mLabelInfo.isHalfCut = false;
mLabelInfo.isSpecialTape = false;


mPrinter.setPrinterInfo(mPrinterInfo);
mPrinter.setLabelInfo(mLabelInfo);
```

However Brother's Android apps are successfully printing without any error.

Comment: Can you add your code just to check?

Comment: Can you guess @GuilhE what will be the reason?

Comment: Are you sure if you are using the right paper type?

Comment: Yes paper type is right, Thanks Guilhe for your help for me

Answer (score 1):

I found solution...

I have done by below code

```
 mPrinterInfo.labelNameIndex = 15;
```

I have tried with for loop where i have used **labelNameIndex** with different value 1,2,3.....15 and tried to print, but in last with 15 it is done.

Comment: Have you tried this:

`mPrinterInfo.labelNameIndex = LabelInfo.QL700.valueOf("W62").ordinal();`

If it works you were using the wrong paper because in my solution I was using "W50" which is ordinal 13.

`public static enum QL700 {
        W17H54(1),
        W17H87(2),
        W23H23(3),
        W29H42(4),
        W29H90(5),
        W38H90(6),
        W39H48(7),
        W52H29(8),
        W62H29(9),
        W62H100(10),
        W12(11),
        W29(12),
        W38(13),
        W50(14),
        W54(15),
        W62(16),
        W60H86(17),
        UNSUPPORT(255);`

Comment: Hi I want to know, how to detect what label size is added in printer at runtime. Is there any method by which we can do that? Getting the Label Size and setting the label size respectively at runtime.

Comment: No, I have no idea of that