# I KEEP GETTING ERROR_WRONG_LABEL on Brother Printer QL-710W

Tags: java, android, printing, network-printers

I have been trying to get my android code to print to a new Brother Printer but

I keep getting ERROR_WRONG_LABEL.

I also get the information:

```
D/Brother Print SDK: no such enum object for the id: -1
```

This is my code:

```
    public void printLabel() {


        Printer myPrinter = new Printer();
        PrinterInfo myPrinterInfo = new PrinterInfo();

        try {

            myPrinterInfo.printerModel = PrinterInfo.Model.QL_710W;
            myPrinterInfo.ipAddress = "12.1.3.45";//not real ip
            myPrinterInfo.macAddress = "";
            myPrinterInfo.port = PrinterInfo.Port.NET;
            myPrinterInfo.paperSize = PrinterInfo.PaperSize.A7;
            myPrinterInfo.printMode=PrinterInfo.PrintMode.FIT_TO_PAGE;
            myPrinterInfo.numberOfCopies = 1;

            LabelInfo mLabelInfo = new LabelInfo();
            mLabelInfo.labelNameIndex = 5;
            mLabelInfo.isAutoCut = true;
            mLabelInfo.isEndCut = true;
            mLabelInfo.isHalfCut = false;
            mLabelInfo.isSpecialTape = false;


            myPrinter.setPrinterInfo(myPrinterInfo);



            myPrinter.setLabelInfo(mLabelInfo);

            //File downloadFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

            Log.i("HEYYYY", "startCommunication = " + myPrinter.startCommunication());

            Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_action_overflow);

            PrinterStatus printerStatus = myPrinter.printImage(map);

            Log.i("HEYYYY", "errorCode-11 = " + printerStatus.errorCode);
            Log.i("HEYYYY", "labelWidth = " + myPrinter.getLabelParam().labelWidth);
            Log.i("HEYYYY", "paperWidth = " + myPrinter.getLabelParam().paperWidth);
            Log.i("HEYYYY", "labelNameIndex " + mLabelInfo.labelNameIndex);
            Log.i("HEYYYY", "printers " + myPrinter.getNetPrinters("QL-710W"));
            Log.i("Label-id", myPrinter.getPrinterStatus().labelId + "");
            myPrinter.endCommunication();




        } catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
}
```

Whenever I put the mac address which I got from the printer page, the error code changes to

```
ERROR_NOT_MATCH_ADDRESS.
```

But without it(setting it to an empty string or commenting it out), it changes to

`ERROR_WRONG_LABEL`.

What is wrong with this code, please?

**UPDATE:**

I inserted the correct mac id and now the error code is

```
ERROR_WRONG_LABEL
```

what do I do?

Comment: You can refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808548/error-wrong-label-when-trying-to-print-wireless-using-android-brother-sdk-for-la

Comment: It did not work for me....what exactly should I refer to there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading through the manual that came with it, I discovered that the ERROR_WRONG_LABEL code occurs due to wrong `labelNameIndex` or wrong `paperSize`.

I set the `labelNameIndex` value to 15 and, voila it worked.

I feel anyone facing this problems should try out various values for the `labelNameIndex`.

Thanks.

Comment: `myPrinterInfo.labelNameIndex = myPrinter.checkLabelInPrinter();` is not working. Please help me in that

Comment: Its been a while since I hacked this printer at my last workplace(2016) and I do not have access to it again. I would advice you to try out various values for the labelNameIndex attribute...(15 worked for me). 
Cheers.

Comment: Also, what error is it giving you? that might give an idea of the issue

Comment: I want to get the labelNameIndex of the printer at runtime and set that into printer. `myPrinterInfo.labelNameIndex = LabelInfo.QL1100.W103H164.ordinal();` this thing is working but not the other way.

Comment: Well i didn't try that. I just experimented and got a value that worked.i.e. 15 in my case. I would advise you to do the same, except your application totally requires you to get it at runtime. I would have loved to help but as I said, I don't have access to that printer again and I have moved on from the company.