# Android printing with Brother SDK via WiFi throws ERROR_WRONG_LABEL despite selecting correct labelNameIndex

Tags: android, printing, brother-print-sdk

I've been trying to print with Brother Print SDK 3.5.1 on Android 8.1.0. I keep getting `ERROR_WRONG_LABEL`.

This is the code I use

```
    void printPdf() {

        // Specify printer
        final Printer printer = new Printer();
        PrinterInfo settings = printer.getPrinterInfo();
        settings.printerModel = PrinterInfo.Model.QL_810W;
        settings.port = PrinterInfo.Port.NET;
        settings.ipAddress = "192.168.1.73";
        settings.workPath = "storage/emulated/0/Download/";

        // Print Settings
        settings.labelNameIndex = LabelInfo.QL700.W62RB.ordinal();
        settings.printMode = PrinterInfo.PrintMode.FIT_TO_PAGE;
        settings.orientation = PrinterInfo.Orientation.PORTRAIT;
        settings.isAutoCut = true;
        printer.setPrinterInfo(settings);

        // Connect, then print
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (printer.startCommunication()) {
                    PrinterStatus result = printer.printPdfFile("/storage/emulated/0/Download/hello world red.pdf", 1);
                    if (result.errorCode != PrinterInfo.ErrorCode.ERROR_NONE) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "ERROR - " + result.errorCode);
                    }
                    printer.endCommunication();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

My printer model is QL-810W and I use the black and red W62 roll.

- I've tried the [Sample Application](https://support.brother.com/g/s/es/htmldoc/mobilesdk/reference/appendix/sample-application.html), where setting `W62RB` in `labelNameIndex` prints fine.
- Changing the roll for different one with different width didn't help.
- I've also tried iterating over numbers 0 to 50 and using them as `labelNameIndex`.
- Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808548/error-wrong-label-when-trying-to-print-wireless-using-android-brother-sdk-for-la/24634521) thread, I thought that the issue may be in specifying the `workPath` attribute. Setting `workPath` to `getContext().getCacheDir().getPath()` results in `ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` instead of `ERROR_WRONG_LABEL`. Not specifying `workPath` and adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` to `AndroidManifest.xml` results in `ERROR_WRONG_LABEL`

#### EDIT

I've modified the Brother Sample app and uploaded it to [GitHub](https://github.com/danhaus/bpsdka351-modified). The app now launches [`Activity_PrintPdf.java`](https://github.com/danhaus/bpsdka351-modified/blob/master/Samples/app/src/main/java/com/brother/ptouch/sdk/printdemo/Activity_PrintPdf.java) by default where I inserted my printing code with hardcoded values at the beginning of `onCreate` method - this *works fine* and prints the PDF file as expected.

Then I created a new Empty Activity project in Android Studio, copy pasted the library, added the imports to `build.gradle` and copy pasted the permissions into `AndroidManifest.xml`. Then I copy pasted the printing code at the beginning of `onCreate` method in [`MainActivity.java`](https://github.com/danhaus/BrotherPrinterAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/brotherprinterandroid/MainActivity.java). Running the app results in `ERROR_WRONG_LABEL`.

[This](https://github.com/danhaus/bpsdka351-modified) is the modified working example app and [this](https://github.com/danhaus/BrotherPrinterAndroid) is the one that results in the error. I want to use the code as native module that I call from my React Native app, so it's important that I manage to set up the printing code from scratch rather than modifying the existing example app.

#### EDIT 2

I've inspected the library with a debugger: when executing `printer.setPrinterInfo(mPrinterInfo)` the library internally calls `private boolean createWorkPath(String dirPath)` of `Printer` object. On return from this method, the debugger shows `Source code doesn't match the bytecode` and seems to forget the created directory. This also internally sets `mResult.errorCode = ErrorCode.ERROR_WORKPATH_NOT_SET`. However, instead of rising any error here the code just silently proceeds, which later results in `ERROR_WRONG_LABEL` when trying to print. Running the same code snipper in the modified [Sample app](https://github.com/danhaus/bpsdka351-modified) works fine.

I'd be grateful if you could help or suggest what to try next.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've now fixed the issue, which was that the Brother library silently failed to create a temporarily folder and instead of reporting an error, it continued and failed later to read the label information. Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212559/android-mkdirs-mkdir-on-external-storage-returns-false/37781236), it is now required to specify runtime file read and write permissions as opposed to the compile-time ones in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
Adding

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
```

at the beginning of `onCreate` before the printing code fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi Dan, I'm having the same problem with Brother SDK that I'm using in my react native mobile app. In iOS all works correctly. In Android I can print but I receive always the error ERROR_WORKPATH_NOT_SET. It's very strange because I set the workPath and the printer print what I send.  Do you have some advice? I'm using the example took from https://support.brother.com/g/s/es/htmldoc/mobilesdk/guide/getting-started/getting-started-android.html. Thanks